# Leaflet Draw - Remove marker without save confirm

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw

I have a map with draw controls to create, edit and remove markers.

All works fine, but I would like to remove the marker just with one click... without save confirm.

I haven't found any posts explaining how I can do this ... or my search is incorrect.
only this code

```
L.EditToolbar.Delete.include({
    enable: function () {
        this.options.featureGroup.clearLayers();
    }
});
```

but this remove all markers... I want remove the markers one by one without confirm

Answer (score 0):

i used this methods and  its worked fine:

```
myMarker = L.marker(map.getCenter(), {icon: ImgSrc}).bindPopup("<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-curve' onClick='removethismarker("+count+",\"Src\")'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></button>").addTo(map);

myMarker._id = count;

map.addLayer(myMarker);
```